# Estoy tratando de actualizar 2 registros con el mismo nombre en mi base de datos

Tags: mysql

Cuando ejecuto la query, me dice que afecto mas de una fila, y es lo que quiero hacer para poder actualizar ambos registros llamados(expressLun, pero con id's diferentes) a la vez con los mismos datos que seria una fecha en este caso. Lo que quiero lograr es que la fecha para los registros, sea la del dia correspondiente a cada uno(expressLun(Lunes)expressMar(Marte)express;Mie(miercoles)expressJue(Jueves)expressDom(Domingo)) con la hora 00:00:00 y la columna experi, tenga la misma fecha que la columna start para el dia que corresponda pero con la hora 23:59:59.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que todos los registros expressLun, expressMar, expressMie, expressJue, expressDom puedan tener la misma fecha en start y expire con las horas 00:00:00 para start y 23:59:59 para expire

*Subquery returns more than 1 row.*

Comment: ¿Y qué error o resultado no deseado obtienes?

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Cree otra tabla para guardar los id's de cada registro de la tabla que contiene los nombres, hice un inner join, pero me sigue diciendo que afecta 2 filas.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar que valores deben ir en `start` y `expire`?

Comment: Los valores de start y expire, se refieren a fechas de comienzo(start) y finalizacion(expire), las cuales se deben renovar semanalmente, son promos por dia las cuales contienen banners para diferentes categorias, cada promo comienza un dia y ese mismo dia termina tal promo a las 23:59:59. El script que pase es solamente para el registro de lunes ya que para los demas seria los mismo, pero primero quiero lograr hacerlo para el registro expressLun

Comment: @SebasF, lo que necesitás es que todos los expressLun tengan el día de hoy en start y en end el día de la semana siguiente?

Comment: Claro, en realidad es que el expire tengan el mismo dia que start, pero en la query que subi me quedo el 7 que lo cambie recien por un 0. Pero si, necesitaria hacer ese update para los campos que tengan en mismo names

Comment: Debe colocar el mensaje de error que le está saliendo; aunque creo que viene causado por `WHEN (SELECT start FROM testfecha WHERE names='expressLun')
` ya que esa subconsulta (de acuerdo a la data que tiene en la tabla `testfecha`) devuelve mas de una fila con `names='expressLun'`;  y la clausula `WHEN` espera una expresión que de un solo valor, para resolver el valor que resulte del `CASE` al que pertenece. Lo mismo para `WHEN (SELECT expire FROM testfecha WHERE names='expressLun')`

Comment: Puse el mensaje de error en otro coment pero lo vuelvo a poner aca.

Subquery returns more than 1 row. Ese es el mensaje de error. No se como podria resolver el update.

Comment: nos mostras como queres que quede la tabla resultado? por ejemplo, que valor queres que tenga start? cual de los dos? porque tu query devuelve dos...

Comment: La sentencia update es notablemente incorrecta, pero si no se ha entendido bien qué es lo que quieres hacer, tampoco se puede decir cual es la sentencia correcta para lograrlo o cual es el problema que tiene tu sentencia actual. Esa información tampoco debiera quedar en comentarios, mi sugerencia es que **edites** la pregunta y expliques en ella lo que quieres lograr (no en términos de SQL sino en términos coloquiales o de negocio).

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro ´Subquery returns more than 1 row´ y se da (como sospechaba) por las clausulas ´WHEN´ que mencioné en mi anterior comentario. Ahora, lo que no esta claro (y ya lo han preguntado varios usuarios ... es ¿Con que valor desea que se actualicen las columnas ´start´ y ´expire´ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitás que los registros expressLun tengan start y expire en el día de hoy, deberías hacer algo así:

```
UPDATE testfecha
SET start = CURDATE(),
    expire = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -1 SECOND)
WHERE names='expressLun';
```

Al campo expire le sumo un día y le resto un segundo, para que tenga el día de hoy pero a las 23:59:59.
Suerte!

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!! Me funciono a la perfeccion!